# Approval status doesn't change

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, flow

I created new documents library in the Sharepoint online Site and new approval flow for the documents in this library.

I see in the flow's history that it ran successfully, but it doesn't change approval status of the document from Pending to Approved.

I tried to approve document from the email I got in the Outlook.

Could you please explain me, how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using flow or an SharePoint Workflow?

Comment: Is your Content Approval on for that library?

Comment: I'm using flow.

Comment: Yes, I turned on Content approval in the Versioning Settings.

Comment: Is version history on? Do you see the changes? Could the change of another field after the approval be setting it back to Pending?

Comment: Document Version History is On. I see changes. I approved document manually at sharepoint.com - status changed to Approved, then I changed content of the document- status changed to Pending. But still I can't approve document from an email.

Comment: In your email, did you use a link which takes you to an Approval Task?  Or did it take you to the Document Library?  The correct way to approve the item is via the Approval Task List, not via the Document Library itself.  This might be the issue.

Comment: @Tally I receive an email with two buttons: Approve and Reject. If I click on Approve then memo field Reason(optional) and button Submit appear. Then I click Submit button and email content changes to Approved with a Date submitted. These buttons take me nowhere. But before approve I can use a link from email which ways me to the document (Word, Excel etc) for approve. So I can check the document's content.

Comment: This sounds different to SP 2013 (which I use), therefore I'm not the right person to answer this.  For what it is worth, I had an issue with approvers approving a document through via the document library via the '...' column.  We had a separate Approval Task List where approvers were supposed to approve docs - part of your question "but it doesn't change approval status of the document from Pending to Approved" made me think of this.  Perhaps search for an Approval Task List in any case (though it could be that for SPO this does not exist, I don't know)..

Comment: @Tally Unfortunately I can't find such thing as Approval Task List in the sharepoint online. Anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had conversation with Microsoft support. They explained me, that default template doesn't change approval status.
The solution is to add a field "Approval status 2" to the document library and add 2 operations to the Microsoft flow (one to the Yes branch and one to the No branch of the Condition). Operation should change "Approval status 2" to the Approved or Rejected.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

The "Start Content Approval" action (which I assume you are using) doesn't actually modify the approval status on an item.  All it does is send out the email/notification, as well as gather a bunch of useful information from the responder(s).

The next thing you need to add is a condition that checks the outcome of your action (that is, so you can branch between Approved or Rejected response from the approver).

[image]

Based on this condition, you can then add new "Set Content Approval Status" actions.  **This action can be used to update to the item's approval status**, based on the output of the previous "Start Content Approval" action (and yes, you will need one of these actions to approve, and one to reject).

[image]